# Deleting iPhone's Apple Support General Log File

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, windows, logs

I have an old iPhone 3GS I'm trying to use back again.
I loaded it up on iTunes and noticed I have 3.8Gb worth of "Other" data stored in it. Keep in mind this is the 8Gb model.

I've tried all conventional methods for clearing up "Other" data, to no avail.
On a more thorough search through the phone's folders I found a very large .log file stored in this directory:

```
var/mobile/library/logs/Apple Support/general.log
```

This log file is 2.7Gb! Considering this is almost half my whole device's memory, I would like to get rid of it.

**Is safe to delete this file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all log files are safe to delete. I’ve often run iCleaner’s file type cleanup, which removes all .log files across the entire filesystem, without any unintended consequences.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I went ahead and deleted the file through SSH (Cyberduck), the phone crashed but I rebooted it and now it's all clear.